# Showing that $|\cos(x)|+|\sin(x)|\le \sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

> Show that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|\cos(x)|+|\sin(x)|\le \sqrt{2}$

My problem is mainly with the modules. I proved it for $f(x) = \cos(x) + \sin(x)$ but don't know how to take this to the modules case. Thanks in advance.

For $f(x)$: take $f'(x) = 0 \iff -\sin(x) + \cos(x) = 0 \iff \cos(x) = \sin(x) \iff x=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi \Rightarrow f(x)\le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Square to get $1+|2\sin(x)\cos(x)|\leq2$ or $|\sin(2x)|\leq1$.

Comment: Can you prove it for $\pm\cos x\pm\sin x$ ?

Comment: You could maybe convince yourself that looking at the inequality over $[0;\pi/2]$, where both $\cos$ and $\sin$ are positive, suffices

Answer (score 6):

By Cauchy-Schwarz:

$(|\cos(x)|+|\sin(x)|)^2\le (|\cos(x)|^2+|\sin(x)|^2)(1^2+1^2)= 2 $

Comment: To which side of the inequality is $2$ equal?

Comment: To the RHS, since $|\cos(x)|^2+|\sin(x)|^2= \cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2$ and  $\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2$=1.

Comment: This also gives the best estimate for $a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)$ or $|a| |\cos(x)| + |b| |\sin(x)|$.

Answer (score 5):

$(x+y)^2 \le 2(x^2+y^2)$.

Put $x=|\cos x|, y=|\sin x|$.

Answer (score 2):

squaring gives $$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)+2|\sin(x)||\cos(x)|\le 2$$
can you finish from here?